# How to render only a part of topojson in d3

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, topojson

I have a `topojson`file which contains all the district in India. I want to render only the districts from specific state. I am unable to figure out how to do that.

Here is my initial code(It renders all districts):

> ```
>     var district_geo_obj = topojson.feature(district, district.objects.india_district);
>     var district_projection = d3.geoMercator()
>         .fitSize([width/2, width/2], district_geo_obj);
>     var district_path = d3.geoPath().projection(district_projection);
>
>     map_svg.selectAll("path")
>         .data(district_geo_obj.features)
>         .enter().append("path")
>         .attr("d", district_path)
>         .attr('class', 'map-margin-const')
>         .style('fill', function(d) {
>             return 'red';
>         })
> ```

This is the screnshot of the topojson file

[image: This is the screnshot of the topojson file]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  var districts = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"];

  map_svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(district_geo_obj.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", district_path)
    .attr('class', 'map-margin-const')
    .style('fill', function(d) {
        return 'red';
    }).style("stroke-width", function (d, i) {
                    if (districts.indexOf(d["properties"]["NAME_1"]) > -1 ) return "1px";   // Not sure about the syntax. But this should do
                    else return "0px";
                })
```

Comment: at least mention reason for downvoting people